# Trying to apply a function to a user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use an external function and apply it to a basic user input. Basically the external function (Code 1) makes the text in (Code 2) print out slowly, like a video game dialog. However the first variable called "intro" is not affected by this function, only the "response" variable is. I don't know how to fix that.

Code 1:

```
import sys,time,os


def typewriter(self):
    for char in message:
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()

        if char !="\n":
            time.sleep(0.1)
        else:
            time.sleep(1)


os.system("cls")
```

Code 2:

```
from typewriter import *

intro = input("What is your name?\n")
typewriter(intro)

response = ("Nice to meet you " + intro + ".\n\
My name is Program.")


message  = intro and response 
typewriter(response)
```

Comment: What is `message = intro and response` supposed to do?

Comment: When asking for input, the user directly sees what they are typing *before* sending it to your program. Are you looking for echo-less prompt, such as [``getpass``](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html)?

Comment: @khelwood i guess nothing. Just deleted it and code still runs.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have no idea what those are. I am self learning. Basically I want the sentence "What is your name" to be printed out slowly, like a video game dialogue, thanks to my funtion. But no matter where I call the function in Code 2, the prompt from "intro" is still printed normally instead of being affected by the function.

Comment: `typewriter('What is your name?')` followed by `intro = input()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it! As it has been mentioned, your `typewriter` function should be receiving the text it should print. But also, "What is your name?" is now being printed by `input`, not by your function.

This works:

```
import sys
import time


def typewriter(message):
    for char in message:
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()

        if char !="\n":
            time.sleep(0.1)
        else:
            time.sleep(1)


intro = "What is your name?\n"
typewriter(intro)
name = input()

response = ("Nice to meet you " + name + ".\n\
My name is Program.")

typewriter(response)
```

Comment: Yeah I ended up doing that and it works, but I was curious to see if it were possible to combine the typewriter function with the input one. You know, less lines, cleaner code and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly function typewriter is not taking any argument to process the data. When you have called the `typewriter(intro)` the first time the message variable is not defined. I think you need to change the typewriter function as follows.

```
def typewriter(message):
    for char in message:
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()

        if char !="\n":
            time.sleep(0.1)
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: The desired effect is to have the sentence "What is your name?" from the variable "intro" in code 2 printed out slowly, like it would be for the "response" variable. so far even with your fix that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

first of all I tried to rename the input in the typewrite function instead of self i wrote message:

```
import sys,time,os


def typewriter(message):
    for char in message:
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()

        if char !="\n":
            time.sleep(0.1)
        else:
            time.sleep(1)


os.system("cls")
```

i would also change the second code to this:

```
from typewriter import *

typewriter("What is your name?\n")
intro = input()

response = ("Nice to meet you " + intro + ".\n\
My name is Program.")


message  = intro and response
typewriter(response)
```

have fun with coding!

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing, but i wanted to see if it was possible to combine typewriter and input.